# Building a Custom XFCE based Ubuntu Mini Remix distribution (14.04) on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: xfce, iso, live-cd

I am building an Ubuntu Mini Remix Live CD (14.04) based on XFCE, and I am using Ubuntu 14.04 for this purpose.

**Now, what I am looking to get on the final iso is:**

1. XFCE desktop with custom (icon, gtk, cursor) themes (some files downloaded from [here](http://xfce-look.org) maybe).
2. Very few applications (chrome, vlc, tomahawk, libre-office and transmission mainly).
3. A custom boot screen.

**So far I have tried:**

Customizer, UCK and Ubuntu Builder for building iso(s), but they have only failed me till now (everything leads to a build failure). I also looked for Reconstructor, but I couldn't find it.

*So manual ways of doing things will be appreciated.*

**Thus, the main problems here are:**

1. How do I customize XFCE to be used in final build?
2. How do I put this XFCE on the build (manually maybe)?
3. How do I install above mentioned applications in the build (manually maybe using .deb files)?
4. How do I build that iso finally?

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have any knowledge of automated tools that work well (maybe someone else does, but in my experience over the years they've been hit-or-miss).

There *are* guides for live CD customization that should work well:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomization and 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomizationFromScratch

Those guides do require quite a bit of command-line usage. You would need to edit Xfce configuration files manually, for example, rather than through a graphical user interface.

Like I said, if anyone else knows of a more automated/user-friendly way to do it, please chime in!

Comment: Your answer is useful thanks. Can you please tell me something more about customizing XFCE and installing debians manually.

Comment: I believe it's the same process as for managing packages on a regular system from the command line (using `apt` or `apt-get` or `aptitude`), but within a `chroot` for the new system. How to manage packages from the command line is a large topic, but there are plenty of tutorials online (I'd recommend using `aptitude`, since it is more newbie-friendly than plain `apt`). There's also Xfce documentation online. I wish I could help you more, but I'm no expert and I don't have time to put together a comprehensive tutorial on something I'm not familiar with (making a custom ISO is a big project).

Comment: Though I am familiar with apt-get, I guess I really need to know more about the chroot. So now perhaps I shall go on to read more about chroot and xfce documentation. Thanks again for your valuable inputs.